# I want to collect duplicated values in SQL and convert them to a number

Tags: sql

I want to count a certain value in a column and output it as a number.
Here is an example:

| id | job |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | police |
| 2 | police |
| 3 | ambulance |

Now I want to count the value "police" in the "job" column and make the result in a number, so because there are two entries with "police" in the column it would be as output the number two. With the value "ambulance" it is only one entry so the result would be 1.

Can anyone tell me how to write this as code?
I have now searched a lot on the Internet and tried myself but I have found nothing that worked.

Comment: A [mcve] should also contain the expected result. And don't forget to add a dbms tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying you want to count how many of each type of `job` there is, right?

```
SELECT COUNT(*), job
FROM tablename
GROUP BY job
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But can you tell me how I can count only the value "police"?

Comment: You'll want to use a "WHERE" clause for that instead of the GROUP BY.

Comment: `having count(*) > 1`?